# SUM values based on date in date range in array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

i'm realy newbie in excel and i need to make advanced functions

I have excel (from Google Calendar) with booking system

```
     A          B          C         
12-01-2012  14-01-2012     8
13-01-2012  17-01-2012     11
15-01-2012  21-01-2012     3
```

A - start date
B - end date
C - number of guests

Now I need to SUM number of guest for all days in year and find every days where was more than 10 reservations.

For example, I need to return

```
 12-01-2012 - 08 guests
 13-01-2012 - 19 guests
 14-01-2012 - 19 guests
 15-01-2012 - 14 guests
```

May I do it without creating large excel file with all days combinations? And how?

I'm working on excel 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done quite simply by using the SUMIFS function. First you need to put each date in column D (set the first date you care about manually, then in D2 below, just say =D1+1 and copy down). Then to count the people for each of those days, put this in E1 and drag down:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C, A:A, ">="&D1, B:B,"<="&D1)
```

This will Sum the passengers listed in column C (must be formatted as numbers, not text - it looks like you might have some text values in there), if that row in column D (each day in the year) is within the range of Column A & Column B.

To find days larger than 10 people, simply have column F (in F1 and dragged down) say 
    =E1>=10

This will say TRUE if column E shows more than 10 people for that day.

Comment: I guess something is wrong in Your formula, i mean "," vs ";"

Comment: @BeataDutkiewicz the use of either a "," or a ";" depends on your version of Excel (region/language settings). In my settings, "," separates terms of a function. Apperently in your settings, ";" separates those terms instead.

Comment: Now i will be remember :D <facepalm>

THANKS

Comment: @BeataDutkiewicz if my answer was helpful please select 'Accepted' next to it.